# Golden Retriever puppy after vaccination

Tags: dogs, vaccination

My Golden Retriever breed puppy is 75 days old. Yesterday, he got his 2nd vaccination. However, after almost 36 hours, he behaves something different such as biting everything, peeing elsewhere, not listening our voice, and irregularity in pooping, sleeping in corner of the room. Is it normal for him? or need any urgent attention?

Answer (score 3):

Any sudden changes after a medical treatment should be brought to the attention of a medical provider immediately.  Call your vet, if they don't have an emergency service call your local emergency vet. Expect you will need to take the pet in for an exam.

Comment: Sorry for late update. He is OK now, actually we contacted vet, he told me that it's very normal for these uneasiness after vaccination to puppy. Since, my dog is in good health, It will last upto 1-2 days. I also asked my friends who have golden retriever adult dogs, almost same experience happened to them.